# Omit nil in string

Tags: string, swift, null, return, option-type

I am practicing swift, and currently writing an easy function to show the schedule of the day. The `return` statement should only include `busyDay` if it contains a value. I hoped this would be done automatic, but it`s not.

```
func scheduleToday (date: String, day: String, numberOfMeetings: Int?) -> String {
    var meetingMessage = ""
    var busyDay: String!

    if var meetings = numberOfMeetings {
        if meetings > 4 {
           busyDay = "Today is a busy day!"
        }
       meetingMessage = "\(meetings) meetings"
    } else {
        meetingMessage = "no meetings today."
     }

    return "| \(date) - \(day) |   Good morning. \(busyDay) You have \(meetingMessage)."
}
```

If `numberOfMeetings` is 4 or less, the returned string says:

```
// | 17th of June - Wedensday |   Good morning. nil You have 3 meetings.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add an else statement to your `if` which sets budyDay to an empty string

```
if meetings > 4 {
    busyDay = "Today is a busy day!"
} else {
    busyDay = ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ternary operator` which will assign empty string if `numberOfMeetings` is 4 or less and your code will be:

```
func scheduleToday (date: String, day: String, numberOfMeetings: Int?) -> String {
var meetingMessage = ""
var busyDay: String!

    if var meetings = numberOfMeetings {

        busyDay = meetings > 4 ? "\(meetings) meetings" : ""
        meetingMessage = "\(meetings) meetings"
    } else {
        meetingMessage = "no meetings today."
    }

    return "| \(date) - \(day) |   Good morning. \(busyDay) You have \(meetingMessage)."
}


let schedule = scheduleToday("1234", "8678678", 3)  // "| 1234 - 8678678 |   Good morning.  You have 3 meetings.""
```